# Error building GCC 9: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found

Tags: debian, compiling, gcc

I've been trying to install GCC 9.5 on Debian Bookworm (12) using gcc-12 which is available in the Debian repos. The build fails at `make` citing it couldn't find `GLIBCXX_3.4.30`. The relevant part of the `make` log is as follows:

```
Making all in po
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/po'                                    
msgfmt -o de.mo ../../../../gcc-releases-gcc-9.5.0/libstdc++-v3/po/de.po                                                               
msgfmt -o fr.mo ../../../../gcc-releases-gcc-9.5.0/libstdc++-v3/po/fr.po
msgfmt: /home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found
 (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.72)                
make[5]: *** [Makefile:550: de.mo] Error 1                         
make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....                       
msgfmt: /home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found
 (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.72)                
make[5]: *** [Makefile:550: fr.mo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/po'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:562: all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:487: all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:19557: all-stage1-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:27270: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1002: all] Error 2
```

I used the following configure options:

```
configure --prefix=path-to-install-dir --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-checking --program-suffix=9.5
```

I don't really understand the error I'm getting. The funny thing is, I can compile GCC 12 from source successfully in the same machine.
The GCC source code is in `/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/gcc-releases-gcc-9.5` while I'm building it in `/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build`.
The most recent version of `GLIBCXX` in `/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6` is `GLIBCXX_3.4.28`

Comment: You might have more luck trying to build gcc9 with gcc10, which is available in the default Debian repos.

Comment: The error indicates that the library `/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6` doesn't have the needed `GLIBCXX_3.4.30` capabilities. Add the output of `strings -d /home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6 | grep -i glibcxx` to the question. To be sure, is `/home/apps/build/gcc` the location of the source code?

Comment: @NasirRiley The source code resides in `/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/gcc-releases-gcc-9.5.0` and I'm building it in '/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build'.

Comment: @NasirRiley `/home/apps/builds/gcc/gcc-9/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6' is in the build directory and it doesn't have `GLIBCXX_3.4.30` (it has glibcxx upto `GLIBCXX_3.4.28`).

Comment: @ajgringo619 Is it not recommenced to build a previous release of GCC with a newer GCC?

Comment: Add that information to the question by editing it. Don't post it in the comments where it can get lost.

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767757/im-using-distribution-x-that-was-shipped-with-compiler-y-but-i-need-compiler) for a sane approach to solving this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your build ends up relying on system libraries which depend on a recent version of `libstdc++.so.6`, but builds an older version of `libstdc++.so.6` itself. The latter is used in preference to the former, even when running third-party tools such as `msgfmt` (which is what fails in your example).

So the problem isn’t strictly speaking the compiler being used for the build, it’s the libraries which were used when building the new compiler’s dependencies... You might be able to work around this by skipping the `libstdc++` build: add `--disable-libstdcxx` to the `configure` options. According to `configure` this produces a working configuration, but I haven’t run the build to check; in particular, I don’t know whether the “missing” `libstdc++` would cause issues, or if the system `libstdc++` would be used instead.

You might find it simpler to use [the `gcc-9` package in unstable](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gcc-9) — it provides all the libraries built correctly. You can access it using a container image or a chroot (see `mmdebstrap`).

Comment: Would disabling `libstdc++` cause any problem down the road? I need this GCC build for building several other libraries which are themselves dependencies of several other programs. I do not want to end up with errors in those builds by disabling `libstdc++` now. Is there a proper way to fix this issue rather than skipping `libstdc++` build?

Comment: See the updated answer. I don’t think there is a “proper” way of doing this, but you can look at [the `gcc-9` packaging in Debian unstable](https://salsa.debian.org/toolchain-team/gcc/tree/gcc-9-debian) to see how it’s handled there...

Answer (score 1):

In order to build GCC which ships its own version of `libstdc++.so.6`, you first need to build a version of [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) which is written in pure C, such as [0.17](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/gettext-0.17.tar.gz).

When configuring, supply a different prefix, such as `/opt/gettext`:

```bash
./configure --prefix=/opt/gettext
```

and temporarily add `${prefix}/bin` to the `PATH` when building GCC.